# ColdFusion 9 / Win Server 2008 - Incorrect Perfmon Values

Tags: coldfusion, windows-server-2008, perfmon

We've recently upgraded from CF 8 Enterprise to CF 9 Enterprise with hotfix 1.

What we have noticed is that some CF 9 counters accessed via perfmon are now giving crazy values.

I recall something very similar happening when we upgraded to CF 8, but that was addressed by the following hotfix:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404026.html (discussion [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/38472))

In that issue the cfperfmon_8.dll was replaced.

Three of our recently upgraded Windows Server 2008 CF 9 servers are displaying a very similar issue. In my Windows event log I'm seeing a lot of these issues:

*The data buffer created for the "ColdFusion 9 Application Server" service in the "C:\Windows\system32\cfperfmon_9.dll" library is not aligned on an 8-byte boundary. This may cause problems for applications that are trying to read the performance data buffer. Contact the manufacturer of this library or service to have this problem corrected or to get a newer version of this library.*

Is there a similar fix available for CF 9?

Comment: Have you filed a bug report? http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html

Comment: @Henry: I've done that now: #83372. If I get any feedback I'll post it here.